# Bootstrap modal shows same every time

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I was working on a school project for a phone selling page and I needed to do a modal for more info on the product. I tried doing a modal for a "more info" button for more products. When I set the second modal on the second product and change the images it does not change the images and text, but it keeps it the same as the first modal button.

Here is the code:

Previous
                          
                          
                            
                            Next
                          
                          
                          
                            
                              
                            
                            
                              
                            
                            
                              
                            
                          
                        
                        
                      
                      
                        
                          **Iphone 11**
                        
                        
                          
                            **$699**

```
                    <!--Accordion wrapper-->
                    <div class="accordion md-accordion" id="accordionEx" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

                      <!-- Accordion card -->
                      <div class="card">

                        <!-- Card header -->
                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne1">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseOne1" aria-expanded="true"
                            aria-controls="collapseOne1">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                             //text <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
                            </h5>
                          </a>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Card body -->
                        <div id="collapseOne1" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne1"
                          data-parent="#accordionEx">
                          <div class="card-body">
                           //text
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                      <!-- Accordion card -->

                      <!-- Accordion card -->
                      <div class="card">

                        <!-- Card header -->
                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo2">
                          <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseTwo2"
                            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo2">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                              //text <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
                            </h5>
                          </a>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Card body -->
                        <div id="collapseTwo2" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo2"
                          data-parent="#accordionEx">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            //text
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                      <!-- Accordion card -->

                      <!-- Accordion card -->
                      <div class="card">

                        <!-- Card header -->
                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree3">
                          <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseThree3"
                            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree3">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                              //text <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
                            </h5>
                          </a>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Card body -->
                        <div id="collapseThree3" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree3"
                          data-parent="#accordionEx">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            //text
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                      <!-- Accordion card -->

                    </div>
                    <!-- Accordion wrapper -->


                    <!-- Add to Cart -->
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalQuickView">Launch
              modal</button>
            <!-- Modal: modalQuickView -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="modalQuickView" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
              aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
                        <div id="carousel-thumb" class="carousel slide carousel-fade carousel-thumbnails"
                          data-ride="carousel">
                          <!--Slides-->
                          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                              <img class="d-block w-100"
                                src="sliki/kontakt/iphone/11 1.jpg"
                                alt="First slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                              <img class="d-block w-100"
                                src="sliki/kontakt/iphone/11 2.jpg"
                                alt="Second slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                              <img class="d-block w-100"
                                src="sliki/kontakt/iphone/11 3.png"
                                alt="Third slide">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <!--/.Slides-->
                          <!--Controls-->
                          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                          </a>
                          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                          </a>
                          <!--/.Controls-->
                          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
                              <img src="sliki/kontakt/iphone/11 1.jpg" width="60">
                            </li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="1">
                              <img src="sliki/kontakt/iphone/11 2.jpg" width="60">
                            </li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="2">
                              <img src="sliki/kontakt/iphone/11 3.jpg" width="60">
                            </li>
                          </ol>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <h2 class="h2-responsive product-name">
                          <strong>Iphone 11</strong>
                        </h2>
                        <h4 class="h4-responsive">
                          <span class="green-text">
                            <strong>$699</strong>
                          </span>
                        </h4>

                        <!--Accordion wrapper-->
                        <div class="accordion md-accordion" id="accordionEx" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

                          <!-- Accordion card -->
                          <div class="card">

                            <!-- Card header -->
                            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne1">
                              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseOne1" aria-expanded="true"
                                aria-controls="collapseOne1">
                                <h5 class="mb-0">
                                  Карактеристики <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
                                </h5>
                              </a>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Card body -->
                            <div id="collapseOne1" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne1"
                              data-parent="#accordionEx">
                              <div class="card-body">
                                Димензии: 150.9 x 75.7 x 8.3 mm (5.94 x 2.98 x 0.33 in) </br>
                                Рам меморија: 4/6 GB </br>
                                Батерија: Non-removable Li-Ion 3110 mAh battery (11.91 Wh)
                              </div>
                            </div>

                          </div>
                          <!-- Accordion card -->

                          <!-- Accordion card -->
                          <div class="card">

                            <!-- Card header -->
                            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo2">
                              <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseTwo2"
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo2">
                                <h5 class="mb-0">
                                  Камера <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
                                </h5>
                              </a>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Card body -->
                            <div id="collapseTwo2" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo2"
                              data-parent="#accordionEx">
                              <div class="card-body">
                                12 MP, f/1.8, 26mm (wide), 1/2.55", 1.4µm, dual pixel PDAF, OIS
                                12 MP, f/2.4, 13mm (ultrawide) </br>
                                Видео: 4K@24/30/60fps, 1080p@30/60/120/240fps, HDR, stereo sound rec.
                              </div>
                            </div>

                          </div>
                          <!-- Accordion card -->

                          <!-- Accordion card -->
                          <div class="card">

                            <!-- Card header -->
                            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree3">
                              <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseThree3"
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree3">
                                <h5 class="mb-0">
                                  Година на производство <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
                                </h5>
                              </a>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Card body -->
                            <div id="collapseThree3" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree3"
                              data-parent="#accordionEx">
                              <div class="card-body">
                                2019, Септември 10.
                              </div>
                            </div>

                          </div>
                          <!-- Accordion card -->

                        </div>
                        <!-- Accordion wrapper -->


                        <!-- Add to Cart -->
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <div class="row">

                          </div>
                          <div class="text-center">

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Затвори</button>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.Add to Cart -->
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

```
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="row">

                      </div>
                      <div class="text-center">

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.Add to Cart -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

This is my javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {$('.mdb-select').materialSelect();
```

});